# Программа для поиска приветливых чисел

Tags: python, оптимизация, арифметика, теория-чисел

Назовём натуральное число приветливым, если для любого натурального n⩾2
энная цифра этого числа равна остатку этого числа при делении на n
. Например, число 2123 является приветливым, так как даёт остаток 1 при делении на 2, остаток 2 при делении на 3 и остаток 3 при делении на 4.

Вот все приветливые числа, не превышающие 10 млн:

> 10 11 20 21 30 31 40 41 50 51 60 61 70 71 80 81 90 91 211 300 302 511
> 600 602 811 900 902 1002 1022 1101 1121 2103 2123 3000 3020 4002 4022
> 4101 4121 5103 5123 6000 6020 7002 7022 7101 7121 8103 8123 9000 9020
> 11013 11031 11113 11131 11213 11231 20004 20022 20104 20122 20204
> 20222 30000 30100 30200 41013 41031 41113 41131 41213 41231 50004
> 50022 50104 50122 50204 50222 60000 60100 60200 71013 71031 71113
> 71131 71213 71231 80004 80022 80104 80122 80204 80222 90000 90100
> 90200 101044 110133 212105 300000 302222 311311 401044 410133 512105
> 600000 602222 611311 701044 710133 812105 900000 902222 911311 1123151
> 2121353 3103035 5010040 5012146 5113015 7020020 7022126

Разумеется, эти числа были найдены с помощью программы:

```
def is_friendly(number):
    str_number = str(number)
    length = len(str_number)

    for i in range(2, length + 1):
        if int(str_number[i - 1]) != number % i:
            return False

    return True

def main():
    for number in range(10, 10000001):
        if is_friendly(number):
            print(number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Однако программа эта работает чудовищно медленно, поэтому не годится для поиска приветливых чисел, превышающих 10 млн.

Пожалуйста, помогите оптимизировать код и ускорить программу.
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Подсказка: очевидно, что первая цифра может быть любая, вторая - только 0 или 1, третья - 0, 1 или 2, и т.д.

Comment: С помощью `pypy` и @Эникейщик я дотащился до 10^10.

Comment: можно еще hex-числа поискать :) @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: @Эникейщик, не до смеха. Я думал задача мелкая. А она глубокая. Есть несколько стратегий сокращения перебора. Все совсем не простые. 10^21 кажется достижимым пределом.

Comment: Дошёл до 10^60. Последнее найденное число меньше 10^20. Их конечное количество?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Простой перебор *m*-значных чисел требует просмотреть *10<sup>m</sup> - 10<sup>m-1</sup>* чисел.

[Эникейщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/%d0%ad%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba) предложил сократить перебор цифр для небольших номеров разрядов - остаток от деления должен быть строго меньше номера разряда.

Ещё один способ сократить перебор - учесть связи между разрядами *i* и *j* если первый делится на второй. В этом случае для любого *n* верно что *n % j = (n % i) % j* (*%* - взятие остатка от деления).
Левая часть равенства - цифра в разряде *j* (*d<sub>j</sub>*), в скобках в правой части цифра в разряде *i* (*d<sub>i</sub>*). Следовательно *d<sub>i</sub> % j = d<sub>j</sub>*.

Например: *d<sub>3</sub> = 2*, тогда *d<sub>12</sub>* может принимать значения *2*, *5* или *8*.

Для сравнения таблица числа кандидатов:

> ```
>  m     все       с учётом            с учётом
>       числа   малых разрядов      малых разрядов и
>                                связи между разрядами
>
>  1       9              9                9
>  2      90             18               18
>  3     900             54               54
>  4     9e3            216              108
>  5     9e4           1080              540
>  6     9e5           6480              540
>  7     9e6          45360             3780
>  8     9e7         362880             7560
>  9     9e8        3265920            22680
> 10     9e9       32659200            22680
> 11    9e10      3.26592e8           226800
> 12    9e11      3.26592e9           189000
> 13    9e12     3.26592e10          1890000
> 14    9e13     3.26592e11          1350000
> 15    9e14     3.26592e12           918000
> .
> .
> .
> 42    9e41     3.26592e39       2970000000
> 43    9e42     3.26592e40      29700000000
> ```

Код ниже использует и малые разряды и связь. Это рекурсивный поиск от второго разряда до младшего. Если поиск сумел построить все цифры, к заготовке добавляется старший разряд. Получившееся число проверяется `is_friendly`. За четыре минуты будут найдены все известные мне приветливые числа. Самое большое из них - двадцатизначное:

```py
for m in range(1, 21):
    found = []

    d = [0] * (m + 1)

    def is_friendly(n):
        return all(n % i == d[i] for i in range(2, m + 1))

    def make_pred(j):
        return lambda e: e % j == d[j]

    preds = tuple(
        tuple(make_pred(j) for j in range(2, i) if i % j == 0)
        for i in range(m + 1)
    )

    def digits(i):
        digits = range(min(i, 10))
        for p in preds[i]:
            digits = filter(p, digits)
        return digits

    def search(i, n):
        if i > m:
            for e in range(1, 10):
                # d[1] = e
                n1 = 10 ** (m - 1) * e + n
                if is_friendly(n1):
                    found.append(n1)
            return

        for e in digits(i):
            d[i] = e
            search(i + 1, 10 * n + e)

    search(2, 0)

    print(m, len(found))
    for n in sorted(found):
        print(f'    {n}')
```

Карта местности:

> ```
>  m: количество: примеры
>
>  1: 10: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>  2: 18: 10 11 20 21 30 31 40 41 50 51 60 61 70 71 80 81 90 91
>  3:  9: 211 300 302 511 600 602 811 900 902
>  4: 24: 1002 ... 9020
>  5: 45: 11013 ... 90200
>  6: 18: 101044 ... 911311
>  7:  8: 1123151 2121353 3103035 5010040 5012146 5113015 7020020 7022126
>  8: 17: 11133163 ... 91232567
>  9:  9: 101044444 ... 900000540
> 10: 96: 1000405404 ... 9123455759
> 11:  3: 30204244844 60200244500 90022046622
> 12: 14: 101044141444 ... 901044647404
> 13:  5: 2103034705335 3111312173713 6002202202362 8010442044544 9111211577917
> 14: 11: 10004044347084 ... 80222222822282
> 15: 19: 101044241414524 ... 910133510389353
> 16:  5: 4020322088789288 ... 8010446444540644
> 17:  1: 81031327310329671
> 18:  1: 902232028812008258
> 19:  0:
> 20:  3: 10000024006072048020 21111111710181114721 80200240800854581880
> 21:  0:
> .
> . здесь нет ни одного числа
> .
> 60:  0:
> ```

С помощью китайской теоремы об остатках можно ускорить перебор ещё примерно в пятнадцать раз. Если известны около *2/3* старших разрядов, младшие разряды можно восстановить без перебора. Программу это сильно раздувает, я её тут не привожу.

Главный вопрос - есть ли приветливые числа большие *10<sup>20</sup>*? Перебор уже дошёл до *10<sup>60</sup>* - ничего не найдено. Я думаю что их нет, доказать не могу.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы использовал Pool из модуля multiprocessing, чтобы создать пул процессов для параллельных вычислений. Это ускорит работу. Метод map из класса Pool вычисляет значения для всех чисел в диапазоне от 10 до 100лямов (или сколько нужно) и потом создаем список дружественных чисел. Обработка идет быстрее. До 100 лямов у меня занял просчет 5 секунд

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def generate_friendly_numbers(max_value):
    # Создаем пул проц. для параллельных вычислений
    with Pool() as pool:
        # Вычисляем значения для всех чисел френдли в диапазоне от 10 до 100 лямов
        friendly_numbers = pool.map(is_friendly, range(10, max_value + 1))
    return [number for number, is_friendly in zip(range(10, max_value + 1), friendly_numbers) if is_friendly]

def is_friendly(number):
    str_number = str(number)
    length = len(str_number)

    for i in range(2, length + 1):
        if int(str_number[i - 1]) != number % i:
            return False

    return True

def main():
    friendly_numbers = generate_friendly_numbers(100000000)
    for number in friendly_numbers:
        print(number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Я использовал numba для ускорения процесса поиска чисел.

```
from numba import njit, prange


@njit(fastmath=True)
def to_int(number): # так как в нумбе не работает int() надо выворачиваться таким образом
    int_number = 0
    for i in range(len(number)):
        i_number = 0
        for j in range(10):
            if (number[i] == str(j)):
                i_number = j
        int_number += i_number * 10 ** (len(number) - i - 1)
    return int_number

@njit(fastmath=True) # ускоряет выполнение вычислений
def is_friendly(number):
    str_number = str(number)
    length = len(str_number)

    for i in range(2, length + 1):
        if to_int(str_number[i - 1]) != number % i:
            return False

    return True

@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True) # включаем распараллеливание и ускорение вычислений
def main():
    for number in prange(10, 10_000_001): # prange тот же самый range но поддерживает распараллеливание
        if is_friendly(number):
            print(number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Комментарии добавил

Comment: А зачем тут функция `a`? )  Она вроде не используется. А так то до 100 миллионов работает за терпимое время

Comment: Так алгоритм точно такой же, это просто ускорение за счет более быстрых вычислений.

Comment: Функция a нужна была для дебага, не заметил её

Comment: Ну явно код работает не быстрее от слова совсем))

Comment: @sLoNcE вы его хоть запускали?)

Comment: Конечно запускал... А вы? Очень медленно работает

Comment: Этот код работает в 100 раз быстрее кода автора

Comment: @rastrey ваш код 25 секунд работает, код из вопроса 7 секунд. При этом ваш код выдаёт гораздо меньше чисел. Мне кажется кое-кто тут врёт.